# QuickStart for Google ARCore not working Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, arcore

I am trying to build a fairly simple AR app (display an AR Avatar of a workout being performed) but I can’t even get ARCore to compile. I downloaded the SDK, and went through running the sample app (which worked) but when I try to call things which exist in the SDK, such as CameraPermissionsHelper, I am unable to do so without a compile error. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening, or can suggest an alternative?

Working in Kotlin and developing for android

Tried using sceneview instead, required major downgrades

Tried moving where the SDK was stored in our project folder